# Map.Entry without type declaration

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, raw-types

I am new to Java, but I need to quickly grasp some fundamentals to be able to work with some basic data structures.

Here's a small example I would like to understand better, namely the `Map.Entry<Integer,String>` part.

```
HashMap<Integer,String> my_hashmap = new HashMap<>();

 my_hashmap.put(20,"twenty");
 my_hashmap.put(30,"thirty");

 for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> m:my_hashmap.entrySet()) {
     System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());
 }
```

It turns out that I can omit the `<Integer, String>` declaration and it makes no difference at all. Is that a bad practice? As far as I understand, under the hood, this is somehow interpreted as the `Object` type so there's no problem, but that doesn't benefit from using generics. Is my understanding correct? Thanks.

Comment: Use two temporary variables to store the key & value, you can see the difference further.

Comment: A `-Xlint:all` to your compile. It's a raw type. `m.getKey()` and  `m.getValue()` will return `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad practice to use raw types.

In your example, since you are simply printing the key and value of each entry, the code passes compilation and works, since it uses the `toString()` method implemented by all classes in order to print them.

If, on the other hand, you want to print the `length()` of the value `String` instead of the actual `String`, you would write

```
System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue().getLength());
```

Now, this won't pass compilation if you changed

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> m:my_hashmap.entrySet())
```

to

```
for (Map.Entry m:my_hashmap.entrySet())
```

since `Object` doesn't have a `length()` method.